# creating noisy image(random noise)

Tags: image-processing, noise-reduction

Just as we can make a noisy image with `imnoise :imnoise` (A, 'salt & pepper',
 [density]). How to add random noise with a particular density?

Answer (score 0):

Additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN)?

```
z = mu + randn(size(im)).*sigma;
im = im + z;
```

Comment: i was saying about random noise and what mu and sigma stands for.i want to add 10%,20% ... random noise to the image.

Comment: Surely you can look up the AWGN definition on the Wikipedia yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Thread your pixels as a List, where 100% equals all pixels.
Simple fill the list  1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Wanted is the ratio amount of pixels

For x to your wanted-number  substract list element at position [x]

the list[x] nr should then be filled with white or be inverted.